# Keep Only First 10 Records in Datagridview Row using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Working with a DataGridView to import data from excel file.
When i I Import Data From Excel to DataGridView it's Import More than 300 records. What i want is to keep only first 10 recods in Datagridview after sorting data in Datagridview.
Remaining row should be deleted.
Please Help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. As it stands, your question is far too broad. This site is for answers to specific issues with existing code. Thanks.

Comment: Whats the code you currently have to import the data? Can you modify your question to include some of your code. If you are using linq or a dataset, you may be able to run a TOP # -SQL (or TAKE # - linq) for the records.

Comment: this will HEAVILY depend on how you're importing the records from the excel file.  If you're using `ADODB` and `Microsoft Ace`, then you can simply adjust your query to pull back top 10 records (do the sorting directly in SQL if you opt to do it this way using `order by` clauses).  If you're using something else, the method will obviously be different.  Show us the code you have so far and we may be able to help some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go from bottom (end) to top (start) and simply delete rows.

```
For x = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 10 Step -1
    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(x)
Next
```

Comment: If the answer is ok for you, mark the question as answered.